# Не обновляется кастомный ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, java, adapter

Есть вот такой адаптер. делаю в активити

```
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Просто ничего не происходит.

Код адаптера:

```
public class FilesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FilesInfo> {

private ArrayList<FilesInfo> mObjects;
private Context mContext;
private View mConvertView;
private ViewGroup mParent;

public FilesAdapter(Context _context, ArrayList<FilesInfo> _objects) {
    super(_context, R.layout.c_files_list_view);
    mContext = _context;
    mObjects = _objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mObjects.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int _position, View _convertView, ViewGroup _parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mConvertView = _convertView;
    mParent = _parent;
    if (mConvertView == null) {
        mConvertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.c_files_list_view, mParent, false);
    }

    ((ImageView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon)).setImageDrawable(mObjects.get(_position).getIcon());
    ((TextView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.list_name)).setText(mObjects.get(_position).getName());
    ((TextView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.list_size)).setText(Double.toString(mObjects.get(_position).getSize()));

    return mConvertView;
}
```

Comment: Решенено переопределением ещё некоторых методов из родительского класса!

Comment: очищайте `ArrayList<FilesInfo> _objects`, а не `Adapter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. лучше использовать BaseAdaper
2. если не лучше, то надо понимать, что в ArrayAdapter лежит свой ArrayList, который и очищается при mAdapter.clear();
3. хорошо бы еще не забывать про паттерн ViewHolder

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, в чем преимущество BaseAdapter'a над ArrayAdapter'ом?.
С паттерном сейчас же познакомлюсь. Спасибо!

Comment: @denqxotl преимущество в том, что ArrayAdapter наследуется от BaseAdapter, и содержит в себе кучу всего, что вы не используете. Фактически вы не используете в своем адаптере функционал ArrayAdapter, а используете только BaseAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно прочитайте [Android Adapter Good Practices](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/).